# iOS 16 Maps issues on Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, maps, ios16

I have updated to Visual Studio for Mac Version to 17.3.6 and support for iOS 16. In my app I use Xamarin.Forms.Maps and a strange issue started appearing. When I zoom out and then try to zoom in on the map, the view freezes and depending on the zoom level and movement in needs long time to process and continue.
I have removed all functionality from the view and only presenting the Map view.
This issue occurs on simulator and real devices on iOS16.

If I'm not processing/requesting/parsing anything it is correct to assume that the issue occurs in the Maps package?

Comment: What version of Xamarin Forms and Maps are you using? Can you create a Github demo for this?

Comment: Here is my setup
.NET SDK /6.0.401,
Xcode 14.0.1,
Xamarin.iOS 16.0.0.72,
Xamarin.Forms.Maps 5.0.0.2515,
I can also create a demo

Comment: Please do so i can check it thanks

Comment: Did you try to run the same code with different vsersions of the package and the xamarin and on the different devices?

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT I checked it, and it seems that is happens only on iPhone 12 Max Pro with iOS16 (now 16.1). Don't see this issue on other devices. I will keep investigating

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the package you used and the release time of IOS 16.
The Xamarin.Forms.Maps package last updating was three mouths ago (before the ios 16), you can't confirm if it supports the ios 16 or not. And according to the official document, there are something new in the native map of IOS 16.

If it works on the any other devices which ios version lower than 16.0, it should be the package problem. You can report it to the github.